# In kotlin what is this syntax: "fun ClassName.funcName(): (Type ) -> Type = {fun body}"

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-dsl

Edited: What and how it work? This is a kotlin dsl language.

```
fun ClassName.funcName(): (Type ) -> Type = {func body}
```

> um this is one of the implementation I found, and also see the concrete syntax to this link: https://dzone.com/articles/the-complete-custom-gradle-plugin-building-tutoria

```
private fun CodeLinesExtension.buildFileFilter(): 
    (File) -> 
        Boolean = 
            if (fileExtensions.isEmpty()) {
                { true }
            } else {
                { fileExtensions.contains(it.extension) } // filter by extension

            }
```

if you *CALL* this one as a arguments in ".filter(...)", what would happed in the "(File)" syntax, is it automatically receive an arguments?

```
someFiles.filter(CodeLinesExtension.buildFileFilter()).forEach{...}
```

Comment: Which part specifically? You might want to look into extension functions and lambdas.

Comment: This adds a new `fun` to an already existing `class` and this kind of function is called *extension function* because it *extends* an existing class by another *function*. You could, for instance, define a `fun Int.isPrime(): Boolean { /* implementation */ }` if you have to check if a number is a prime number somehow frequently.

Comment: @Henry Twist, I found this in gradle custom plugin by DZONE, see here: https://dzone.com/articles/the-complete-custom-gradle-plugin-building-tutoria

Comment: `buildFileFilter` is a high-order extension function that returns function type that accepts `File` and returns `Boolean` (like `Predicate<File>` in java)

See:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions

Comment: :Henry & :Hya-E, I thank you for the info. really thanks.

Comment: @IIya-E, oh um so sorry for miss-spelling out your code-name. Again thanks for the swiftly-solid-detail.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things at play here.

`fun SomeClass.funcName()` is the syntax for declaring [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions). These are used just like regular methods of the class `SomeClass`, but can be defined outside of the class, and it's especially useful on classes that you don't control.

The return type of the function you mention is `(File) -> Boolean`. This expression describes a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types). In this specific case, it is the type of all functions that take a `File` as single argument, and return a `Boolean`.

This means that your `buildFileFilter()` function is an extension function that itself returns a function `(File) -> Boolean`.

As you can see in the function's body, inside the `if` statement, there are braces to define the blocks of the `if`-`else` (`{ ... }`), but also braces inside those blocks. This is because Kotlin uses braces for [lambda expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) (literals for anonymous functions).

`{ true }` is a lambda expression that represents a function that may or may not take arguments, but returns `true` every time.

So this code:

```kotlin
if (fileExtensions.isEmpty()) {
    { true }
} else {
    { fileExtensions.contains(it.extension) } // filter by extension
}
```

returns either:

- `{ true }` - a function that takes a `File` as argument and always returns true, or
- `{ fileExtensions.contains(it.extension) }` - a function that takes a `File` as argument and returns whether `fileExtensions` contains the extension of the `File` that it receives (`it` is the implicit name for the `File` argument)

Note: the fact that these functions take a `File` as argument is inferred by the compiler based on the return type of `buildFileFilter()`.

> if you CALL this one as a arguments in ".filter(...)", what would happed in the "(File)" syntax, is it automatically receive an arguments?

`filter()` itself actually expects a function as argument. The function you pass to `filter()` is called a predicate, because it takes one element of the list as argument and returns a `Boolean` that says whether this element should be included in the resulting list.

So if you apply `filter` to a `List<File>`, the predicate expected by `filter` is exactly of type `(File) -> Boolean` (it says whether we should put this `File` item in the resulting collection).

Calling `buildFileFilter()` returns a function as we have seen, and the function is perfectly of the right type to use it in `filter`. The `File` argument of the function returned by `buildFileFilter()` will be given by the `filter` function itself when it calls your filter function.

Comment: Great Thanks!, Now I understand it is an ***"extension-fun"*** that return a ***function***/"lamda-func" that also return a specified Type.